# "due to A or due to B" is the same as "due to A or B"?

Tags: conjunctions

I found "due to A or due to B" in a book.

Can I use "due to A or B" instead of "due to A or due to B"?

If so, which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two expressions are equivalent.

Reasons to use the longer would include emphasis, cadence, or sometimes in a complex sentence it might eliminate ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

A little caution is needed in your interpretation here. The author may be trying to distinguish between 'or' and 'xor', the *[exclusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)* or.

Logically, **A or B** implies one of: **A, B,** (**A and B**)

while
**A xor B** implies one of: **A, B**.

Context should tell you what the author intends, but sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: At least to me, the longer form "Due to A or due to B" has more of an exclusive feel that the short form.

Comment: Yes, the phrasing itself is a bit of a flag that something special might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

'Due to...' implies one and only one cause. e.g., 'Due to the recent economic crisis there will be no Christmas bonuses this year.' To me, it sounds awkward to say 'Due to the recent economic crisis and the embezzlement of funds, there will be no Christmas bonuses this year.' Personally, I don't speak or like the phrase 'due to'. There are people who tend to overuse this phrase repeatedly when they could simply state the facts: 'Because of the recent economic crisis...'.